# Test suite failed to run - Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jestjs, dependencies

Can anyone help me with this error? I have to unify two repositories, and have to update an change some dependencies. I dont know if that is causing the problem or is something else.

FAIL  src/**tests**/models/oficios/Caratula.spec.ts
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

root\node_modules\jest-preset-angular\node_modules\pretty-format\build\index.js:412
  options?.printFunctionName ?? DEFAULT_OPTIONS.printFunctionName;
          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1258:14)
```

Here are the configuration files:

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  verbose: true,
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "ts"],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom:[
    '<rootDir>/src/app/**/*.ts'
  ],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
  },
  transform: {
    ".+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
};
```

baberlrc:

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": false }], ["@babel/preset-typescript"]],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "version": "2021-12", "decoratorsBeforeExport":true }]]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "npm test -- -u --coverage && ionic-app-scripts build && node moveScript.js",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@types/npm": "^2.0.31",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^3.1.4",
    "big.js": "^5.2.2",
    "brmasker-ionic-3": "^1.6.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.3.1",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.4.22",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.10",
    "ionicons": "^4.6.3",
    "jszip": "^3.10.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mixin-deep": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.5.0",
    "ngx-order-pipe": "^2.0.4",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.63",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "source-map-resolve": "^0.6.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tar": "^4.4.11",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.8",
    "ngx-quill": "^4.3.2",
    "quill": "~1.3.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.22.9",
    "@babel/core": "7.22.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.22.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.22.10",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "@types/jest": "29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "20.11.24",
    "@types/quill": "~1.3.10",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^13.1.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.14.0",
    "ts-jest": "25.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is unclear, and it may be difficult for users to understand what is being asked. I suggest reviewing the 'How To Ask' guide before asking questions. If you provide the code that your having issues with, it'll be easier for contributors to understand the issue at hand.